# User friendly import of events from web to Google Calendar?

Tags: import, calendar, google-calendar

I would like to create a web page promoting local events. I would like the users to be able to easily import the events to their calendars (Google Calendar particularly).

Is there any option to import an event to Google Calendar from web directly?

Case scenario:
User just found a theatre event on my website, that he would like to go to. Instead of manually rewriting the event to its calendar, he would choose whether he wants to Import only selected day of the show or if he wants to import all days when the show is played. He would click the desired button to export this event into his Google calendar. Google login window would open and after logging in, the user will have a new event or series of events in his calendar.

I know I can achieve this somehow by creating iCal files, that the user would have to manually import to Google Calendar, but isn't there any other way to do the import more user friendly?

Comment: This would depend how you are displaying the Google calendar on your website. If you are using Google's calendar "widget"/iframe then Google provide this feature _out of the box_. User clicks on event and there is the option to "copy to my calendar". Also, providing you publish your "public" Google calendar address, then anyone can already import events to their own Google calendar.

Comment: OK, everything is just a plan right now, so there is no problem using Google Calendar widget. But is there some API to be able to create custom links (at the event page i don't want to have calendar, just the "import button")? And what about imports to other Calendars? Outlook? Thunderbird (if there is any)? Or any other major? Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has an [Event Publisher's Guide](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/1186917) for just this purpose:

> ### Let people save an individual event from your site
>
> You can add a Google Calendar event reminder button to your site by inserting a special snippet of HTML into your page. Users who click on your button can quickly save your event on their Google Calendars, which will help remind them about your event and about your website. By adding a Google Calendar event reminder button to your site, you acknowledge that you understand and agree to the [Program Policies](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/partner_program_policies.html).
>
> [Do it now](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/3033039)

There is [similar functionality for linking to a Microsoft Calendars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh846807.aspx#single):

> ### Creating a single-event link
>
> To create a single-event link, create a URL in this format.

```
http://calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent&dtstart=START_DATE_AND_TIME&dtend=END_DATE_AND_TIME&summary=EVENT_TITLE&location=LOCATION_TEXT`
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw I have found similar functionality for Microsoft Live: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh846807.aspx#single

Comment: Good find.  I added that to the answer.